# How to find nearest points using latitude and longitude from a DocumentDB collection?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using Microsoft's DocumentDB to store locations of hundreds and thousands of geographic locations in the UK. A document from the database collection looks like the following.

```
  {
    "CommonName": "Cassell Road",
    "CommonNameLang": "en",
    "Street": "Downend Road",
    "StreetLang": "en",
    "Indicator": "SW-bound",
    "IndicatorLang": "en",
    "Bearing": "SW",
    "LocalityName": "Fishponds",
    "ParentLocalityName": "Bristol",
    "Easting": 364208,
    "Northing": 176288,
    "Longitude": -2.5168477762,
    "Latitude": 51.4844052488,
  },
```

What type of DocumentDB query could I use based on the user's latitude and longitude to find the nearest points from the collection?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need a geospatial function like ST_NEAR or ST_DISTANCE. This is **not currently available** - you can check the status of the feature [here](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6333261-geo-spatial-indexing).

Short-term, especially if have < 1000 documents, you might be able to use an existing geospatial library e.g., [System.Spatial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.spatial.geographyoperationsextensions.distance(v=vs.113).aspx) and perform processing client-side. Alternatively, you can use a JavaScript library like [GeoJSON Utils](https://github.com/maxogden/geojson-js-utils) within stored procedures to do this.

Comment: Aug 13, 2015 - Announcing Geospatial support in Azure DocumentDB! https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/blog/announcing-geospatial-support-in-azure-documentdb/